# package 'gazebo_ros' not found

Tags: ros2

i have ubuntu 22. and installed ros2 humble. then i installed turtlebot3 as shown in emanual but when im running the command
export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger
ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo empty_world.launch.py.
it gives me error as Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): Caught exception when trying to load file of format [py]: "package 'gazebo_ros' not found.

i checked and packages was installed also through
dpkg-query -L ros-humble-gazebo-ros | grep cmake

i have sourced the environment already

Comment: By any chance, did you forget to "source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash"? It should appear in "ros2 pkg list".

Comment: yes, just did it to check it again

nom@nom:~$ source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash

nom@nom:~$ ros2 pkg list

and gazebo_ros does appear in list

Comment: previously i had installed the humble-ws and turtlebot3_ws seperately and it was working... cause of storage issue i had to reinstall and it started giving me issue,
ryt now i am installing the turtlrbot3 package directly in humble_ws and colcon build to check if it works or not